# Saving checkpoints when training on TPU?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tpu

I am training a model on TPU-V8, as there are 8 core TPU in this TPU configuration. Previously when I worked on multiple GPU using tf.distribute.MultiWorkerMirroredStrategy I had to specifically specify which GPU is the chief GPU among the cluster of GPU, and the chief GPU is responsible for storing the checkpoints. Similarly, do I have to specify which core is the chief core in the TPU and save the model parameter through it or can I simply save the model parameter as model.save_weights('path')??

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Does [this](https://www.kaggle.com/mgornergoogle/five-flowers-with-keras-and-xception-on-tpu#Save-the-model) reference help you? Thanks!